# Which sets are dense in the discrete metric?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve the below problem.

> For any set $X$ define the discrete metric on $X$ by $d(p,q) = 0$ if $p = q$ and $d(p,q) = 1$ if $p \neq q$. Prove that this is indeed a metric. With this metric, which subsets of $X$ are open? Which are closed? Which are dense?

I don't have any trouble showing that every subset of $X$ is open and every susbet is closed. I'm having trouble finding which subsets are dense. The definition from Rudin is:

> $E$ is dense in $X$ if every point of $X$ is a limit point of $E$, or a point of $E$ (or both).

My attempt is as follows.

Let $E \subset X$ be dense in $X$, and fix $x \in X$. Either $x$ is a point of $E$ or a limit point of $E$. I'm not sure what to do if $x \in E$, but let's consider the case where $x$ is a limit point of $E$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, $N_{\epsilon} (x)$ intersects $E$ nontrivially. Taking $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, in the discrete metric we have $N_{\frac{1}{2}} (x) = \{x\}$, so for every $x \in X$, $\{x\} \subset E$. Then $\bigcup\limits_{x \in X} \{x\} \subset E$, so $E = X$.

It seems that I've concluded that if $E$ is dense, then $E = X$. I don't think I need to prove the converse because every step is reversible, but I still haven't treated the case where $x \in X$ and $E$ may not have any limit points, so the proof I wrote may be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if $X$ is discrete and $E$ is dense in $X$, then $E=X$.

The simplest way to show this is with the following reasoning:

1. By definition, $E$ is dense if and only if $\overline E = X$, where $\overline E$ denotes the closure of $X$.
2. Because $X$ is discrete, $E$ is closed.
3. Because $E$ is closed, $E=\overline E$.
4. Therefore, $E=\overline E = X$.

---

With your definition of denseness, the proof that you wrote is probably the easiest way of proving $E=X$.

Note that you have correctly proven the statement that if $E$ is dense, then $E=X$. This is independent of whether $E$ has any limit points or not.